# Pulling Data From .MDF or .LDF into Excel without a server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel, toad

I've been at this for over a week straight now.
I am trying to set up an excel file to pull data from a live .MDF and/or .LDF file on a server. Because of the sensitivity of the files, and updating live, I want to work with just dummy back ups of the files.

But I can't seem to find anything that lets me just edit the .MDF and/or .LDF files. I cannot set up my own server. How can I pull the data from these files into excel without setting up a server data base? I have downloaded Oracle, Toad, SQL Manager, etc. nothing seems to work.

Or is there a way to set up a folder on my desktop and "trick" the software into thinking that is a server?
Thanks!

Comment: No, you just simply cannot do that. In order to get at the data in a `.mdf` SQL Server database, you **must have** some version of **SQL Server** installed.

Comment: You could install SQL Express and attach the .mdf file. It's free and can be installed on your desktop.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for answering!